# Insert data to SQL without html forms

Tags: mysql, forms, post

I'm a beginner web developer, and I'm coding a small project, mostly in order to learn the practice.

I am now writing an `HTML` page (with **JavaScript**) that collects data from users. The HTML page is pretty complicated and by the time a user had finished filling all the fields, not all the data is in the form - some of it was calculated by *JavaScript* and stored, either in `localstorage` or in `attribute`s of certain HTML elements.

How can I submit the data into a `MySQL` database? (using methods with `POST` in `PHP`, like [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp), only allows to send data that is in `<input>` tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use ajax(Asychronous Javascript And Xml) to send data to the server or you can use jQuery to do it..
eg: `$.ajax({
     type: "get",
     url: some_php_script.php,
     data: {"list": list_data},
     success: function(data){
                   do some work here with the data recieved
     }
     });`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to send the values to a PHP script, then you can do whatever you want. You can use javascript to either:

- Post the values via `XmlHttpRequest`, or "AJAX":
- Add `<input>`s to your form with the proper values before submitting it (these can be hidden visually or with `type="hidden"`)

If you are just getting started with PHP, MySQL, or really any language - try your best to avoid w3schools for information. The page you linked to has a classic example of [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain), and uses the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) `mysql_*` functions. See the PHP manual on [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) before you get started.